# Is it possible to program on Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, ide, windows-runtime, windows-rt

Is there any way to install a C++ compiler or Ruby/Python interpreter on WinRT. (or is there any other way to program in a language beside JavaScript and beside online compilers and IDEs)

To be more specific: Can I program USING MY WinRT NOT FOR WinRT. SO can I open an app or notepad ON WinRT and than compile the code ON WinRT (NOT "FOR" but "using"). Thx.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for an IDE (integrated development environment) that would run on Windows RT (ARM based) devices and allow you to compile programs for other target platforms? While there're no technical restrictions for such an app, there don't seem to be any in the store at the moment. The only one to feature a Ruby interpreter seems to be [InstantRuby](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/64438b0c-b188-4a92-b918-41ba0f86b85e), though it doesn't look like you could actually create a program with it.

There are multiple code editors already available though (in no particular order as I haven't tried any of them yet):

- [Code Writer](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/5149f454-94a7-40bc-90ef-eafd38355079)
- [NotepadRT](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/592a5cf2-f685-49a2-9242-8aa7c284c333)
- [HaxPad](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/d6e5c55d-9c4f-47dc-bb36-20bea0df9664)
- [CodePlus](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/18882cca-c9de-4aff-9680-05e53aef7edb)

Comment: Thanks for the HaxPad shout out.  This actually drove me several purchases.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be use a remote desktop app on the WindowsRT computer. Install the IDE or other development tools on a regular PC, and use remote desktop to login. In this way, the WindowsRT system acts as a terminal ("thin client"), and can support about any IDE and compiler chain that you can install on the PC.

If you really want to build software *on* WindowsRT: if this was possible, it would most likely involve developing *for* WindowsRT, since at least if you want to do local debugging, your code will have to run on WindowsRT also.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need to jailbreak the device. Python 2.7.3 has been ported to WinRT (calls to native code wont work). Vim along with a few other editors have also been ported. See here for more information on the jailbreak http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158 and on the ported apps http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092348

Answer (score 2):

As of now I was only able to execute powershell scripts and js/vbs scripts with `cscript`/`wscript`.

I was able to compile C# code on Windows RT since it has C# compiler (I had to tweak `csc.rsp` file a bit to remove missing dlls), but it is impossible to load unsigned assemblies, so that's largely useless. Even getting developer license (with `Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration` cmdlet) doesn't allow execution of unsigned 'desktop' .NET apps. Need to try with 'ModernUI'.

Answer (score 1):

I ported SharpDevelop here, for C# http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/sharpdevelop-rt-edition-beta-code-windows-forms-directly-on-windows-rt/ Your device must be unlocked to allow desktop apps, info is on xda developers.